# Making an increasing list of polynomials simultaneously squarefree

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Is the following conjecture obviously false? I have checked on a computer for $n$ up to $200$. Since that is pretty low, and there doesn't seem to be any good upper bound on the minimum value of $t$ needed,  I wouldn't be surprised if it was still false.

> Let $n > 1$ be squarefree. Then there exists a $t \geq n$ such that all the numbers
> $$n + t^2 - k^2, \qquad 0 \leq k < t$$
> have squarefree part greater than $n$.

Of course I would love to kill this with something like Schinzel's hypothesis H, but that doesn't seem to be enough since the list of polynomials involved grows with the input.

Here is the list of the minimal $t \geq n$ that works for each squarefree $1 < n \leq 203$, organized as ordered triples $(n, t, s)$, where $t$ is the minimum required $t$, and $s$ is the smallest squarefree part of all the $n + t^2 - k^2$. At first I was hopeful that one could choose $t$ close to $n$, but some of the data points actually need very large $t$. Perhaps the thing to do is to parameterize $t = an + b$ with $b < n$, and hopefully observe that $a = 1$ and small $b$ works a lot of the time.

(2, 2, 5)

(3, 6, 14)

(5, 5, 14)

(6, 6, 17)

(7, 8, 22)

(10, 10, 29)

(11, 12, 34)

(13, 13, 38)

(14, 14, 41)

(15, 30, 74)

(17, 30, 19)

(19, 22, 62)

(21, 21, 62)

(22, 25, 71)

(23, 30, 82)

(26, 27, 79)

(29, 33, 94)

(30, 30, 89)

(31, 32, 94)

(33, 78, 41)

(34, 34, 101)

(35, 70, 174)

(37, 85, 206)

(38, 38, 113)

(39, 108, 62)

(41, 41, 122)

(42, 126, 69)

(43, 46, 55)

(46, 46, 137)

(47, 48, 67)

(51, 54, 158)

(53, 57, 166)

(55, 110, 274)

(57, 95, 86)

(58, 62, 181)

(59, 64, 71)

(61, 93, 66)

(62, 67, 78)

(65, 65, 194)

(66, 77, 74)

(67, 74, 214)

(69, 93, 254)

(70, 91, 103)

(71, 122, 314)

(73, 143, 358)

(74, 84, 86)

(77, 135, 106)

(78, 390, 114)

(79, 92, 262)

(82, 95, 271)

(83, 92, 266)

(85, 187, 149)

(86, 86, 257)

(87, 135, 89)

(89, 137, 122)

(91, 148, 130)

(93, 177, 138)

(94, 110, 178)

(95, 120, 334)

(97, 355, 193)

(101, 101, 302)

(102, 2346, 134)

(103, 112, 326)

(105, 2947, 145)

(106, 154, 157)

(107, 176, 458)

(109, 113, 334)

(110, 143, 167)

(111, 252, 219)

(113, 145, 402)

(114, 300, 137)

(115, 320, 146)

(118, 128, 373)

(119, 206, 146)

(122, 150, 421)

(123, 222, 131)

(127, 166, 458)

(129, 207, 146)

(130, 845, 139)

(131, 208, 194)

(133, 427, 206)

(134, 158, 449)

(137, 161, 218)

(138, 462, 237)

(139, 148, 434)

(141, 159, 173)

(142, 191, 163)

(143, 268, 182)

(145, 377, 226)

(146, 162, 181)

(149, 307, 158)

(151, 244, 166)

(154, 322, 173)

(155, 160, 179)

(157, 205, 178)

(158, 225, 166)

(159, 742, 183)

(161, 189, 538)

(163, 338, 838)

(165, 3555, 506)

(166, 188, 541)

(167, 481, 239)

(170, 961, 311)

(173, 235, 642)

(174, 212, 206)

(177, 954, 213)

(178, 202, 197)

(179, 277, 183)

(181, 359, 229)

(182, 226, 233)

(183, 732, 219)

(185, 435, 274)

(186, 186, 557)

(187, 850, 238)

(190, 535, 359)

(191, 216, 211)

(193, 727, 241)

(194, 244, 206)

(195, 880, 211)

(197, 355, 218)

(199, 386, 259)

(201, 471, 218)

(202, 229, 659)

(203, 212, 218)

Comment: What are the polynomials you are talking about?

Comment: @JohnGowers: sorry, I just meant that if instead we only required those numbers to be squarefree when $0 \leq k < N$ for some constant $N$, then maybe the conjecture would follow from Schinzel's hypothesis H, using the polynomials $X^2 + n - k^2$ (of course we would get them to be simultaneously prime, not just squarefree).

Comment: For large $n$ , it will be more and more difficult to find such a $t$. Maybe it helps , if you post one solution $t$ for each of the squarefree numbers from $2$ to $200$. It is well possible that the Schinzel-hypothesis (generalization of the Bunyakovsky conjecture) implies this claim.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks! I have posted the smallest possible $t$ for each such $n$, plus the minimum of the squarefree parts of the relevant numbers. Most of them are close to $n$, but some of them are not which is what made me nervous about whether this is true

Comment: @babu_babu I think with higher $t$ we could also achive higher minimal squarefree parts, but this of course just an intuitive guess. But apparently sometimes the smallest $t$ is much larger than $n$ , so brute force will probably soon become very time-consuming. We will probably need clever restrictions to $t$ to find a solution more or less efficiently.

Comment: I programmed it in PARI/GP and $n=273$ seems to be already a very hard case.

Comment: In fact, for $n=273$ , we need $t=63\ 603$ !

Comment: For $n=345$ we get $t=75\ 465$

Comment: Hard cases occur over and over again, but I arrived at $n=643$, until which the conjecture is true

Comment: I arrived at $n=751$, the process more and more slows down. I think, we need restrictions to find the number $t$ more quickly.

Comment: The question is whether there exists a $t \geq n$ such that the set $A(t, n) = \{n+t^2-k^2 | 0\leq k < t\}$ does not intersect $B(c)$ for any $c\leq n$, where $B(c)$ represents integers of the form $cm^2$. Can we consider the simpler problem of whether these exists a $t \geq n$ such that the set $A(t, n)$ does not intersect $B(1)$? If the original problem's answer is yes, then this simpler problem's answer must also be yes.